# Save fields of branched structure with dynamic names in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, matlab-struct

I need to know how to save just one branch of a structure in MATLAB.
The structure contains more levels with more fields per level. For example:

```
data.level1.level21  
data.level1.level22
```

I want now to save the branches `data.level1.level21` and `data.level1.level21` individually. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
firstLevelName = fieldnames(data);
secondLevelNames = fieldnames(data.(firstLevelName{1}));

for pL = 1:length(secondLevelNames)
        save([filename '.mat'], '-struct', 'data', firstLevelName{1}, secondLevelNames{pL});
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure-saving method that you're [trying to use](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/save-structure-fields-as-separate-variables.html?refresh=true) doesn't work quite the way you are expecting. All the arguments after your struct variable name are fields of *that* struct to save.

The way MATLAB is interpreting your code is that you're trying to save the `level1`, and `level21` fields of `data` which obviously doesn't work since `level21` is a subfield of `level1` *not* `data`.

To save the nested fields, the easiest thing is probably to create a new variable pointing to the structure `data.level` and then call `save` on that and specify the specific fields to save.

```
level1 = data.level1;

for pL = 1:numel(secondLevelNames)
    save(filename, '-struct', 'level1', secondLevelNames{pL});
end
```

If you actually want the double nesting in the saved data, you would need to create a new structure containing only the data that you wanted and then save that.

```
for pL = 1:numel(secondLevelNames)
    newstruct = struct(firstLevelName{1}, struct());
    newstruct.(secondLevelNames{pL}) = data.(firstLevelName{1}).(secondLevelNames{pL});

    save(filename, '-struct', 'newstruct')
end
```